# Can I have more than 1 key identifier when using Beyond Compare for data files?

Tags: beyondcompare

I have two data files that are not in perfect row alignment which is causing my compare to look worse than it truly is.  Is there a way to have more than 1 key identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Sessions > Session Settings > Columns tab > Double click on the column name which you want to make a key identifier> you will get a window showing column # handling

Here you can use the check box [] Key to mark or unmark the column as a key

You can also cick on rules icon which is just below tools menu. Icon looks like a referee wearing a hat.
This will directly get you the same window as column handling